# JDBC driver for Microsoft SQL Server: automatically switch reads and writes between slave and master

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I am using JDBC driver for MSSQL. Is it possible to switch the reads and writes between master and slave like MySQL? [MySQL client can automatically send queries to a read/write source host, or a failover or round-robin load-balanced set of replicas.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/connector-j-8.0-en/connector-j-source-replica-replication-connection.html)

Like mentioned in documentation for MySQL but for MSSQL.

Comment: MSSQL does not have a "slave". If you mean Availability Groups, see the [jdbc doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/jdbc-driver-support-for-high-availability-disaster-recovery).

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to switch the reads and writes between [Primary] and [Readable Secondary Availibility Group Replicas]?

Yes.  In SQL Server that's called [Read-Only Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/jdbc-driver-support-for-high-availability-disaster-recovery?view=sql-server-ver15#read-only-routing).